# how know if a Type has inherited some other type?

Tags: c#, reflection

how know if a Type has inherited some other type ?

```
Type t;
// i get the t from somewhere
bool b = t.IsInhertitedFrom(typeof(BaseType));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bool b = t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseType))

and to check if type implements interface use:

bool b = t.GetInterface(typeof(IMyInterface).FullName) != null